# Unity stick image to the right of text with varying width

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, I have a text which is centered in the middle of the screen.
To the right of that text i want to have an image stick to the text.
When the width of the text increases by X, I want the image to move to the right by X/2 and vice versa.

I already put a Content Size Fitter on that text, so the width of the Rect Transform is actually always just the width of it's content.

The thing that has to be done now somehow is to make the image stick to it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change the anchor of the image to be the right border of the text instead of the left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, solved myself about 30sec after asking..
All I had to do was to change the anchor of the image to be the right border of the text instead of the left.